# Google play services 5.0.77

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

From the 25th of june two unrelated apps that are using ads started to have this NPE

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at zo.a(SourceFile:172)
   at aeh.a(SourceFile:120)
   at afw.run(SourceFile:14)
   at afy.run(SourceFile:30)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I think this is related to google play services update. Is anyone able to help me out on this issue?

Just to confirmed that the issue is related to play service I have managed to get this from crashlytics from a thread called AdWorker:

```
thread
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
   at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
   at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:813)
   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:973)
   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1282)
   at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:207)
   at zo.a(SourceFile:147)
   at zo.a(SourceFile:170)
   at aeh.a(SourceFile:120)
   at afw.run(SourceFile:14)
   at afy.run(SourceFile:30)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

it is not the right place... but there is no place at all where to report them

Number of exceptions it has double from 1 july, it is now almost 3 times what it was the 27th of june.

[Issue on android google code project](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72854)

### The discussion is now in this thread on [admob google Heading group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/DkjtCx_Zvn8)

Last reply from google "We're aware of these crashes and are working on fixes. We hope to push out these fixes in the next week or two." (July 7th)

Comment: What in that error messages makes you think its from play services?

Comment: It is the only thing the applications where I can see the exception share. Plus the exception started on multiple versions the 25th of june when the play services update was rolled out

Comment: I am getting same reports since new version of play services started to be distributed

Comment: Which parts of the Play Services are you using (ads, location, games, ..)? We are using G+, GCM and AdMob/DFP. By finding a common element, it should be easier to find the root of the issue.

Comment: AdMod the thread causing the issue is called  AdWorker

Comment: I know it's not an answer but can this be related ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526722/googleplayservice-need-update-but-no-update-in-playstore

Comment: Just a question : which device do you use ? Because for me, only Samsung devices (tablets and smartphone) don't work, others devices works.

Comment: Google Play services 5.0 is now rolled out to devices worldwide, maybe this can fix the problem. Source : http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2014/07/google-play-services-5.html

Comment: How bad would it be to install an uncaught exception handler and ignore the exception if it's this one? I'm considering trying that if nothing else works, but well I have plenty of horror stories on where things go wrong when you use an uncaught exception handler like that. ;)

Comment: Someone sent in a crash with ART, which reveals slightly more info about the crash:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String vh.a(android.content.Context)' on a null object reference
at zo.a(SourceFile:172)
...

Comment: I tried using google play services version 5077000 . But got no luck. Still getting crashes

Comment: After more than 1 month this bug was finally fixed with the latest GPS version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found this solution by Mateusz Matela at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/DkjtCx_Zvn8.

I have tried on a Motorola DEFY+ that crashed from this bug two out of three times. It seems to work even when the warnings assositated with this bug appears in the log. It even says "AdWorker thread thrown an exception". My ads even reappeard when continuing to use the app.

```
final UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            if (thread.getName().startsWith("AdWorker")) {
                Log.w("ADMOB", "AdWorker thread thrown an exception.", ex);
            } else if (defaultHandler != null) {
                defaultHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("No default uncaught exception handler.", ex);
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: I guess this is a possible solution. Thanks

Comment: I just released our app with this workaround yesterday and according to ACRA this works!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Okay, this works for me. It's pretty hacky, but until Google fixes these bugs, I have no other alternative (besides removing Admob altogether). Thanks.

Comment: I added this to the onCreate() method of my application subclass, is that correct?

Comment: According to Google Play crash reporting, it seems that this workaround is very effective. I could not reproduce the bug though, so I'm not sure the bug has no other side effects.

Comment: According to Crashlytics there is no difference for me with or without this workaround. Could it be that Crashlytics is reporting this bug even though it doesn't lead to a crash with this workaround?

Comment: Also for me. Using this workaround the Developer Console does not report any crash while Google Analytics shows that the crashes are still occurring. Don't know who is right, as I can't reproduce the crash with my devices...

Comment: If the crash happens after the users backs out of the app (which some reports suggest), this workaround may cause the app to hang as the app will be prevented from shutting down properly.  Anyone seeing increased ANRs after implementing?

Comment: You are right. Before this workaround I never had any ANRs now I see that there are 3 ANR reports in my Developer Console. :( Google takes so long for fixing their GPS bug. I think I'm going to look for alternatives where I can mediate AdMob. (e.g. MoPub)...

Comment: For me this workaround doesn't work, I still have serveral reports acording this bug

Comment: After more than 1 month this bug was finally fixed with the latest GPS version.

Answer (score 4):

Today, Google posts this : http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2014/07/google-play-services-5.html

And now it works for me. Just try again to update the GooglePlayService in your mobile and update your ADT.

**Edit :**

Code to check GPS version :

```
// Check if GooglePlay Service is good;
            resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this.getActivity());
            if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this.getActivity(), 1).show();
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_googleplayerror, container, false);
                    return rootView;
                } else {
                    Log.i(Tag, "This device is not supported.");
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Interestingly the large amount of crashes I see on my end seem linked to this release if looking at the crash by date.

Comment: Could please provide a link for download google-play-services version 5.0 I can't' find it on their site. Also I couldn't update from my 17 version of google play services to 18

Comment: here the link : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=fr

Comment: I also edit my answer for you (example code). This redirect the user to GPS on GooglePlayStore if he need update

Comment: I think you have an other problem not related with this.

Answer (score 2):

I got exactly same errors on different android versions after updating admob to google play services.
I think it can't be solved on user side.

Comment: Yes I agree, nothing we can do. I posted the question to have some confirmation from other people as Google is not very responsive on this type of issues. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is related to Play services update, see sample crash log below. Since it crashes onCreate it might be happening when user click on an advert or a specific type of advert

```
USER_COMMENT=
ANDROID_VERSION=4.1.2
APP_VERSION_NAME=8.9
BRAND=samsung
PHONE_MODEL=GT-I9100
CUSTOM_DATA=
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxxxx/com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at acm.a(SourceFile:215)
at acz.onTransact(SourceFile:58)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ck$a$a.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
... 11 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
at acm.a(SourceFile:215)
at acz.onTransact(SourceFile:58)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ck$a$a.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Not sure the two exceptions are related, I have noticed this one as well but numbers are much lower that the java.lang.NullPointerException at zo.a(SourceFile:172)

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing the exact same issue with one of my apps since Jun 25th as well. You are right this is a Google issue, I think I have managed to resolve it by updating my Android Support Library to version 20 (I was using android-support-v4.jar) and my Google Play Services to version 17.

I am not sure which of the two revisions resolved this but it's been 24 hours and the Crash reports have stopped.

EDIT:
Sorry this is still not resolved. But I got a response from the AdMod SDK team that they are looking into it. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/DkjtCx_Zvn8

Comment: I can't see why support library will have any impact on play services. By Google play services 17 you mean the 4.4.52 right (At google they like to increase duplication by having 2 versions for the same thing)? if so no that is not the solution either.

Comment: I know support will not have an impact on Play Services, just stating what I did to resolve it. Yes, revision 17 is 4.4.52. I have not seen a crash report since upgrading, but again it's been only a day.

Comment: I got this errors after updating stand alone admod to google play services 4.4.52

Comment: Yes, you are right. Updating to 4.4.52 has not resolved it. I see a whole bunch of these errors again today. I am surprised why there is not other mention of this issue on the on the web. Have you opened a bug report with Google on this?

Comment: I have created an issue with Google. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72854

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial solution and it seems (so far) to fix 100% the crashes: you should postpone the ad request a few milliseconds to avoid this crash!

Simplified example:

```
    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

    if (handler != null) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 200);
    }
```

Comment: Interesting... did you try other values for the delay like 100ms or something?

Comment: I did this last night and had an error this morning, so it is not a complete fix. Too soon to tell if it helps at all yet.

Comment: what about the onPause,onResume,onDestroy - did you leave them intact?

Comment: This solution is not working for me. Crashes are still happening in the newer version of my app.

Comment: Trying that I face a problem due to many "threads" and Google Ad incomplete requests (I guess) which in some cases (Wildfire S - 2.3.3, Samsung Galaxy S II - 2.3.5) stuck the whole screen (contains WebView) and does not load anything. Sure that solution doesn't help in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered a workaround.

In my case, I was showing the ad from within a service running in a custom process. For example:

```
    <service
        android:name="com.example.MyService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:process=":svc" 
        />
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml, I then set the same android:process attribute for the declared AdActivity, and the problem went away.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:process=":svc"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" 
        />
```

In the case of my application, I don't particularly care which process the ad activity runs in, so this workaround is sufficient. Hopefully this will be of some use to others.

Answer (score 0):

I have find temporary semi-solution. I use **thiagolr** advice above with delayed ad request:

```
    Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};

if (handler != null) {
    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 200);
}
```

Also I removed onResume and onPause methods, so I don't know which solution helps me,
but beforee this workaround I had 100-130 java.lang.NullPointerException at zo.a(SourceFile:172) per day. After this workaround I had 6-10 NullPointerException per day. If you want you could try this solutions separately to define which of them helps.

My removed methods in activity:

```
//    @Override
//    public void onPause() {
//      adView.pause();
//      super.onPause();
//    }
//
//    @Override
//    public void onResume() {
//      super.onResume();
//      adView.resume();
//    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/DkjtCx_Zvn8

Some have had a success by adding android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" to activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" in the manifest.

I'm rolling out a new version with that fix now. Will see in a couple of days if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Move to using other ad sdk. I tried most of the thing mentioned and error still remains.
And i personally hate applying such hacks in code. So decided to switch rather using google ad sdk with crashes and bugs.