# GooglePlayService need update but no update in PlayStore

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

I developed an app that use GoogleMap. I just updated Android Plugin in Eclipse (with Android L libs), and re-imported GooglePlayService libs, etc.

So, I recompiled and it's working great on my phone (Sony Xperia Z in 4.4.2), on GenyMotion Emulator (4.4.2), on Nexus 7 (4.4.2). But it is not working on two Samsung Galaxy S4 (4.4.2) and another Samsung tablet in 4.4.2. In fact, I checked the version of GooglePlay Service this way:

```
resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this.getActivity());
        // resultCode = ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED;
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this.getActivity(), 1).show();
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_googleplayerror, container, false);
                return rootView;
            } else {
                Log.i(Tag, "This device is not supported.");
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        }

        else {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tracking, container, false);
        }
```

So, in devices where the app doesn't work, Android detects that GPS (GooglePlayService) is not up-to-date, and redirects to GooglePlayStore, but in Play Store there are only two buttons : Uninstall and Open. I also read that import `GooglePlayServiceForFroyo` can resolve the pb. But, why is it working on some devices but not on other even if they are on the same Android version?

Comment: Can you update GPS OUTSIDE of your app ? (i.e by just visiting the Play Store without launching your code).

Comment: try to enable the Gps services in mobile...

Comment: I can't update GPS from PlayStore : only two buttons : "Open" or "Unistall"

Comment: It works too on a Nexus 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try seeing if the problem has fixed itself? The rollout for Google Play Services 5.0 just finished rolling out (1 hour ago), as mentioned in this blog post: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/07/google-play-services-5.html

It might be that you used the 5.0 SDK before the rollout was finished, but since your device had not received the update, it would fail to run.

Comment: Hello Wayne, I have the same problem as Cocorico describes. We get an "UPDATE" code in a Galaxy S4 4.4.2 (Argentina) but when we click Play Services Dialog to check for an update in Play Store there is no update to download. We are using Play Services 5+ in our build.gradle as described in Play Services Docs.

Comment: Are you using 5+ or 5.0+ in your build.gradle? I would recommend using 5.0.+ since that has already rolled out and should work fine.

Comment: I'm using 5.0+ as "Settings up Google Play Services" docs recommends but most of our devices don't see any update on Google Play. I'm really worried about this because our next release will include Google Play Services for the first time and I don't want to make it difficult to users. I'm working at Mercadolibre android app, regards.

Comment: I correct myself. We are using 5.+ as docs recommends:

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'

I'll try 5.0+ thanks for your time.