# after updating google-play-services, google play says update needed even though latest is installed

Tags: android, google-play-services

testing on HTC Legend running Android 2.2.

I'm in the process of updating my app, which currently works fine on the device.

While updating some functionality i also updated the compatibility-v4 to 19.1.0 (from 18) and google play to 18 (from 7).

What now happens is that when i call

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable
```

in onCreate() i get SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED back. I have a procedure in place in my app with nice user message, a button to open app store etc, but when that button is clicked and google play opens, the Google Play Services app IS updated, it only has an "open" and an "uninstall" button!

I am at a loss as to what to do. If anybody has any idea, pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Please Ensure Devices Have the Google Play services APK.

Comment: Yeah, as i wrote, they do have it installed, but googleplayservicesutil says i need to update it, but when in the google play app store, it IS updated, Hence my question.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526722/googleplayservice-need-update-but-no-update-in-playstore

Comment: Related too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457689/google-play-services-5-0-77#autocomment37978951

Comment: But no answer at this moment

Comment: Haha we asked basically the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try seeing if the problem has fixed itself? The rollout for Google Play Services 5.0 just finished rolling out (1 hour ago), as mentioned in this blog post: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/07/google-play-services-5.html

It might be that you used the 5.0 SDK before the rollout was finished, but since your device had not received the update, it would fail to run.